# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic 2

Here is my code....

```
<div class="messagesholder" 
      *ngFor="let chat of chatval | orderby:'[date]'; let i = index;let first=first;let last = last;">
           {{last ? callFunction() : ''}} 

       <div *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser" >
       {{checkdate(chat.date)}} 
       <p class="chat-date"  id="abc" #abc>{{msgdate | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>

</div>
```

Here is my checkdate function

```
checkdate(date)
  {
    var res = date.split(" ");
    var A=res[0];
    var local=localStorage.getItem('chatdate');
    this.msgdate="";
    if(local === undefined || local === null)
    {
      this.msgdate=A;
      localStorage.setItem('chatdate',this.msgdate);

    }
    else if(local !== undefined)
    {
      console.log(local != A);
      if(local != A)
      {

        this.msgdate = A;
         localStorage.setItem('chatdate',this.msgdate);
      }
    }

   }

    callFunction(){
    this.content.scrollToBottom(0)
  }
```

It's work.But I getting this error.

> FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. Error:
>   Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'April
>   10, 2017'. Current value: ''.

Because I go this working by having these lines in my code :

```
constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

ngAfterViewChecked() {
//explicit change detection to avoid "expression-has-changed-after-it-was-checked-error"
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
```

But Now I am getting this error

> database.js:62 FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user
>   callback. RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Your error in title and body doesn't match.

Comment: You are calling detect changes that triggers after view checked which is calling detect changes, and so on. Move detect changes to ngAfterViewInit and see if it works.

Comment: @unitario I used ngAfterViewInit But still get this same err

Comment: The problem is that change detection is activating the view which triggers `callFunction()` which in return active ngAfterViewChecked and your new round of change detection. I think you should have a look at your interpolation logic: `{{last ? callFunction() : ''}}` and move that out of the template. As a suggestion you could create a directive containing your call function and pass `last` as `@Input` which will execute the `callFunction` if `last` is true. More information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40080541/function-is-getting-called-many-times-by-using-template-interpolation

Comment: @unitario.I didn't understand ...

Comment: Ok so simply put: remove callFunction() out of your template syntax. I believe that is what is causing your problem.

Comment: @unitario.I removed callFunction().But Still I am getting this err Exception was thrown by user callback. Error: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'April 10, 2017'. Current value: ''.Pls kindly help me....I have no idea... : (